# How do I compile for debugging in Mercury programming language?

Tags: debugging, compilation, mercury

Using Mercury 14.01.1 on Ubuntu 14.04. Have installed four grades, including debugging grades, from source code. Tried each of the following without success (files/directories missing)

$ mmc --debug filename

$ mmc --decl-debug filename

Q. What should I have typed instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mercury is less than user-friendly when it comes to compilation grades.   Your installation will be configured to use a default grade, for example hlc.gc.  However when you give the --debug option it simply adds .debug onto this grade string (hlc.gc.debug) rather than choosing the most appropriate debug grade (such as asm_fast.gc.debug).  Depending on the debugging grade that you've installed I suggest typing:

```
mmc --grade <my debug grade> --make my_program
```

To explicitly specify the grade you want to use.  Note also that --make is required to build a whole program or library, without --make mmc will only compile a single file which is usually not what you want.  I hope this helps, if you're still having trouble you can write to users@mercurylang.org

Thanks.